# Is Ubuntu 18.04 available on Intel 11th gen?

Tags: 18.04, intel

I'm going to replace my laptop.
And I really need the 18.04 version of Ubuntu.

So, I'm thinking of the Intel 11800h.
Is Ubuntu 18.04 available on Intel 11th gen?

I am sorry that I am not good at English.
Thank you!

Comment: we do not provide hardware support :) "Intel 11800h" and  what does that have to do with being or not being able to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I heard that the old ubuntu cannot be installed on the latest cpu.

Comment: Just curious why do you need this specific Ubuntu version?

Comment: Hey mino! "*Running Ubuntu directly from either a USB stick or a DVD is a quick and easy way to experience how Ubuntu works for you, and how it works with your hardware. Most importantly, it doesn’t alter your computer’s configuration in any way, and a simple restart without the USB stick or DVD is all that’s needed to restore your machine to its previous state.*" Read this article for more information: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Answer (score 0):

I recently purchased Lenovo Thinkpad E15 with i5 11th gen, but the operating system I installed was Ubuntu 18.04 because of the projects my company worked on worked on only 18.04 version of ubunutu.

I am currently facing many challenges including no sound and not able to change brightness, even after going through many solutions available I was not able to rectify those.

So in order to answer you, it is available but will not work fabulously.